# Bootstrap-table displays both "No matching records found" and Records in bootstrap-table with Firebase realtime database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I am using bootstrap-table and trying to display a table with data from a firebase realtime database.

The contents of the database render correctly, however I am *also* seeing a "No matching records found" message in my table.

Using the search and sort functionality also clear the table completely and a refresh is needed to restore the data.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import firebaseDb from "../firebase";

const StarTrekTable = () => {
  var [contactObjects, setObjects] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    firebaseDb.child("unwatched").on("value", (snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.val() != null)
        setObjects({
          ...snapshot.val(),
        });
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
        <div class="container">
          <h1 class="display -4 text-center">Star trek series</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div className="col-md-12">
          <table data-toggle="table" data-pagination="true" data-search="true">
            <thead className="thread-light">
              <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Series</th>
                <th>Season</th>
                <th>Episode</th>
                <th>Stardate</th>
                <th>Air Date</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {Object.keys(contactObjects).map((id) => {
                return (
                  <tr>
                    <td>{contactObjects[id].title}</td>
                    <td>{contactObjects[id].series}</td>
                    <td>{contactObjects[id].season}</td>
                    <td>{contactObjects[id].episode}</td>
                    <td>{contactObjects[id].stardate}</td>
                    <td>{contactObjects[id].airdate}</td>
                  </tr>
                );
              })}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default StarTrekTable;
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

[Table shows both records as expected and "No matching records found"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PLyj.png)

[Image of my Firebase realtime database setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNQih.png)

Answer (score 0):

On the first render of your component, your `contactsObject` is `{}`, which leads to `<tbody>` being empty on the first render. Somewhere else in your code, probably somewhere in bootstrap, the "No matching records found" is added into the source. Once your listener has found the unwatched episodes, downloaded, parsed, and added them to the `<tbody>` react then removes the entries it has added (none) and then inserts the new entries. Because "No matching records found" was added outside of React, it doesn't know that it is there and isn't removed. Rather than let whatever other code is adding this row in, define it yourself when you are still loading data or the table is empty.

If you aren't already using [`react-bootstrap`](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction), you should use it so that the original JavaScript bundled with Bootstrap doesn't fight with React for control like you've seen here.

**Note:** When rendering arrays of data in React, make sure to specify a `key` for each entry so that React can efficiently manipulate the entries on new renders.

Cleaning up some other things too, this gives:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import firebaseDb from "../firebase";

const StarTrekTable = () => {
  // - renamed variables to reflect content
  // - used array instead of object
  // - used const instead of var
  const [episodeData, setEpisodeData] = useState([]);
  const [episodesLoaded, setEpisodesLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // store Reference for attaching and detaching listeners
    const unwatchedRef = firebaseDb.child("unwatched");
  
    // because you use a `.on` listener, don't forget to store
    // the listener so we can detach it
    const listener = unwatchedRef
      .on("value", (snapshot) => {
        if (!snapshot.exists()) {
          // no data to show and/or unwatched is empty
          // update state variables
          setEpisodeData([]);
          setEpisodesLoaded(true);
          return;
        }
        
        // Use forEach to maintain the order of the query, using `...snapshot.val()`
        // for the whole result will often lead to unexpected results.
        const freshEpisodeData = [];
        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
          freshEpisodeData.push({ ...childSnapshot.val(), key: childSnapshot.key });
        });

        // update state variables
        setEpisodeData(freshEpisodeData);
        setEpisodesLoaded(true);
      });
      
    // when component is detached, remove the listener
    return () => unwatchedRef.off("value", listener);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
        <div class="container">
          <h1 class="display -4 text-center">Star trek series</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div className="col-md-12">
          <table data-toggle="table" data-pagination="true" data-search="true">
            <thead className="thread-light">
              <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Series</th>
                <th>Season</th>
                <th>Episode</th>
                <th>Stardate</th>
                <th>Air Date</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              { !episodesLoaded
                ? (
                  <tr key="data-loading">
                    <td colspan="6"><i>Loading...</i></td>
                  </tr>
                )
                : (episodeData.length === 0
                  ? (
                    <tr key="data-empty">
                      <td colspan="6">No unwatched episodes available. You're all caught up!</td>
                    </tr>
                  )
                  : episodeData.map(({ key, title, series, season, episode, stardate, airdate }) => (
                    <tr key={key}>
                      <td>{title}</td>
                      <td>{series}</td>
                      <td>{season}</td>
                      <td>{episode}</td>
                      <td>{stardate}</td>
                      <td>{airdate}</td>
                    </tr>
                  )))
              }
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default StarTrekTable;
```

**Note:** For static arrays that are unlikely to change, your database structure is fine, but I would strongly advise against using numerical keys for your data (`0`, `2`, etc.) and instead use something else like (`S01E01-02`, `S01E03`, etc.) or Firebase Push IDs. Take at this (yet still valid) [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) for the reasoning.